# What is this syntax error?

Tags: javascript, html

when i copied this code from page error found that there is syntax error in this line in dreamweawer.

```
<a href="javascript:ajaxpagefetcher.load
   ('bob','sub/content2.htm',false,'',['page.css'])">Load Content 2</a>
```

Please suggest answer..
thanks

Comment: "Load Content 2" is not valid JavaScript for various reasons ... you may want to post some more code so people can see the problem in a context.

Comment: the page from which i catch the code is

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/ajaxpagefetcher.shtml

please suggest any correction

Comment: **List** the **exact** error, please.
Did you include ajaxpagefetcher.js in your page?  Did you download the ajaxpagefetcher.js?

Comment: thanks for the help 
i got my ans....

Comment: @rajesh: And what is the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have a problem because of the line break ?

It might cause a "semicolon insertion", separating your statement in two.